# How can I deploy my webworker to Firebase on my Ionic React App?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, web-worker

I have a fairly simple react app in which I'm using a webworker to do some stuff on the background process some data send it back to the main thread where the component is being rendered and updates the state of the data that the worker retrieves back.

it's a very simple implementation.

```
const worker = new Worker('src/webworker.ts', {
  type: 'module',
});

const Simulation: React.FC = () => {
// the component starts
// and does what it needs to do with the worker
```

Im pretty much done and I wanted to upload it to firebase so that I can show it without needing to have my development environment setup on my computer.

But when I do the build with `ionic build` and then `firebase init` & `firebase deploy` and then access the app that firebase hosted the webworker never gets executed, and its behavior is completely missing.

The only thing I see while inspecting network requests when i run the app is
Request URL: https://so2s....a.web.app/src/webworker.ts
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404
Remote Address:199.36.............
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

My only guess is that the file is not being served, or perhaps it is but it's being compiled back to JavaScript in a way that i am not capable to account for yet.

The file is completely accessible when doing `ionic serve` and it works perfectly when its being done locally.

I do not really know where else to look about this.

I'm a little stuck, what could be done?